# NAudio how to read value of position in wav and how to get total number of blocks

Tags: c#, naudio

I am new to NAudio API and I have a few simple questions.  I am trying to make a graph of each channel of a wav file.  I have a WaveStream from a WaveFileReader and I would like read the wav at each BlockAlign and get the the channel data (the sample value) I think I need to do this for a sampling of blocks depending on the sample rate.  My question is:

1. How to get total number of blocks
2. How to read channel data sample values
3. How to get sample rate or samples per second (or whatever format)

Any suggestions or pointers would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not know anything in DSP
with NAudio or any other audio library there is no way to get No. of blocks 
you need to read about digital signal processing